# raw folder cannot be resolved - android

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I am using AndroidStudio, which is based on intelliJ Idea. I know that this issue was often presented here, but I created inside `res` folder some `raw` folder and copy-pasted some mp3 file `jam.mp3`. But I can't make my raw folder (inside my res one) resolved by my IDE and I tried numbers of tricks suggested in SO.

I have this line of code

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jam);
```

and `raw` cannot be resolved, how can I fix it ? (Btw, I can't find in my IDE an equivalent of the `eclipse`'s `clean`)

Comment: did R. refer to Your package? Sometimes it happens that android.R is importet because of inattention...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I am a true newbie to android... but I don't have any import of R.

Comment: "Clean" in IntelliJ is at Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: first of all `AndroidStudio` is not a good place for a newbie to start android programming. It is in beta version and is not stable and lack many functionality. I would recommend to use eclipse as IDE atleast while you are new then you can move to `AndroidStudio`.

Comment: @Devunwired I rebuilt the project and I am told : `Gradle: cannot find symbol variable raw`

Comment: I got no practise with AndroidStudio but try to set an import like this --import com.yourpackage.yourmainactivity.R;-- This is the way to refer R. to Your package

Comment: @Opiatefuchs , yes but it changes nothing. In fact, in the `R.java` file, I can't see any reference to a raw folder.

Comment: then it will gonna be very difficult. It is possible that Your R.java is not generated, this could happen of any error inside a xml.layout file. If there is an error, R.java would not be genrated again, this is how it is in Eclipse, don´t know if this points to AndroidStudio too.

Answer (score 1):

In **IntelliJ IDEA**, you have a context menu option "Force generate R.java" when you stand on such a resource file.

Your song name should start with **Capital Letter** , Should not contain special characters like **. _** etc..

If this not solves your problem then try restarting your IDE.

Comment: sorry but when I right click on the R.java file, I can't find 'force generate R.java'

Comment: And remember, the generated R file is not in the project "gen" directory. It is in the "out" directory (drill down to your project).

Comment: thank you but where do I find 'force generate R.java' in InelliJ IDEA ?

Comment: @user1611830 I am not using `IntelliJ IDEA`. I 've gone through few websites and told some solution. Why don't you try Eclipse?